# expected continuation not received

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

I am using below jcl code to create pds but i am getting error

```
 000001 //HERC01A JOB (COBOL),                                               
 000002 //             'abc',                                 
 000003 //             CLASS=H,                                              
 000004 //             MSGCLASS=H,                                           
 000005 //             REGION=9000K,TIME=1440,                               
 000006 //             MSGLEVEL=(1,1)                                        
 000007 //STEP1    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                          
 000008 //SYSOUT      DD *                                                   
 000009 //TEMDATA     DD DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                            
 000010 //               DSN=HERC01.TKARTHI.EXAMPLE,                         
 000011 //               SPACE=(TRK,(45,45,50)),                             
 000012 //               DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=800,DSORG=PO),       
 000013 //               UNIT=SYSDA                                          
 000014 //
```

o/p:

```
                                                J E S 2   J O B   L O G         
07.47.07 JOB   26  IEF452I HERC01A  JOB NOT RUN - JCL ERROR                     
    1     //HERC01A JOB (COBOL),                                                
          //             'abc',                                  
          //             CLASS=H,                                               
          //             MSGCLASS=H,                                            
          //             REGION=9000K,TIME=1440,                                
          //             MSGLEVEL=(1,1),                                        
          //            USER=HERC01,PASSWORD=            GENERATED BY GDL       
    2     //STEP1    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                           
    3     //SYSOUT      DD *                                                    
    4     //TEMDATA     DD DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                             
    5     //*              DSN=HERC01.TKARTHI.EXAMPLE,                          
    6     //               SPACE=(TRK,(45,45,50)),                              
    7     //               DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=800,DSORG=PO),        
    8     //               UNIT=SYSDA                                           
 STMT NO. MESSAGE                                                               
-                                                                               
    4     IEF621I EXPECTED CONTINUATION NOT RECEIVED                            
    5     IEF605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD                                  
    6     IEF605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD                                  
    7     IEF605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD                                  
    8     IEF605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD                                  
******EOF-TTR=000101************ BOTTOM OF DATA **************1689-BYTES********
```

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieam800/m010544.htm *"the continuation of the operand begins in columns 4 through 16."*

Answer (score 8):

The issue, as pointed out by others, is that JCL looks for continuation on or before column 16.

Below I provided a view of the JCL in ISPF Edit using the `Cols` line command.

[image]

In your example note that the line after `TEMDATA` is counted as line 5 and has been converted to a comment noted by the new **`//*`** because of the incorrect continuation and so the following lines were considered new JCL statements.

[image]

Here is a reformatted version using a traditional approach.  Note that the DDName `TEMDATA` is aligned to allow an 8 character DDName followed by the DD statement and then the positional parameters.  This allows for fairly clean coding regardless if DDNames are less than 8 characters and alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
000009 //TEMDATA DD DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                            
000010 //           DSN=HERC01.TKARTHI.EXAMPLE,                         
000011 //           SPACE=(TRK,(45,45,50)),                             
000012 //           DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=800,DSORG=PO),       
000013 //           UNIT=SYSDA
```

you have DSN=, SPACE= to far to the **right**. **Columns** are important in **JCL**